# Difference between startUpdatingLocation (with Distance Filter) and significantLocationChanges

Tags: ios, core-location, distance, cllocationmanager

I'm developing an app where updating location is required after about 50km. If I set a `distanceFilter` on my `locationManager` to 50000. Would calling `startUpdatingLocation` then be more battery efficient than using `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges`? (Seeing as significantLocationChanges don't use the `distanceFilter`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the info provided, `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges` is the correct choice.  The reason, and answer to your question, is that `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges` is a service that your app registers for and will continue to run even when your app is suspended or terminated. However, `startUpdatingLocations` is registered at the app level and unless you specifically ask the user for permission to run in the background via `requestAlwaysAuthorization` your location service will terminate when the app is suspended or terminated.  You will also need to register your app for location background Mode and provide Apple with good reason for or run the risk of app rejection.